# Docker network data exchange

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have an application serving three modules: a reader, a parser and a publisher. The reader and publisher are basically static services but the parser can be different depending on the source. Even the programming language can be different for the parsers. Since I dont want to implement a reader and publisher for each and every parser variant, I would like to split the services into separate containers which leads me to my question.

How can I forward the output of a single service container and trigger the next one within a docker network?

What would you recommend?

- If I am running the application as one big service I can just make a function call, provide the required parameters and run along the workflow. Is that still possible somehow after splitting the services into containers? That would be nice.
- Do I need to have a docker network internal file interface? But then I would additionally need a file reader in each and every service.
- Do I need a socket connection between the containers?

What would be most feasible or what else would be possible?

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: That overall flow could be a good match for a messaging system like RabbitMQ.  Those services from the outside seem very small to me, though; how much work is the parser doing, and how much work would serializing its output be?  Could these three parts be a single program in a single container, launching an ordinary subprocess to run the out-of-tree parser?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DavidMaze
Reader: Currently just reading files with various extensions. In future maybe also reading TCP/IP streams / mqtt services.
Publisher: Can serve various services like, file writing, mqtt or amqp.
Parsers: Currently interpreting the content of the reader, mapping it to a predefined pattern and finally serializing it for publishing. But each parser can be highly individualized which leads to a customized application. If I then also add reader+publisher into each application I will probably struggle with maintenance and deployment at one stage.

Comment: Assuming when the reader or publisher service changes one day.
In a modulized application I just need to change the service and provide it to my customers.
But when having it in each and every application I would need to touch all of them, doing the changes mulitple times and deploy the **correct** service to every single customer.